# Change the sequence using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Want to sequence with SQL query.
Is there any shorter way to update it, or should I update the whole table.

My table as follows:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Name VARCHAR(10), Seq INT)

INSERT INTO @tab VALUES('A',1),('B',1),('C',1),('D',3),('E',4),('F',5),('G',6),('H',7),('I',8)

SELECT * FROM @tab ORDER BY Seq
```

I want to change the sequence show column with ID 7, 8, 9 at the top.
My desired output should be

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Name VARCHAR(10), Seq INT)

INSERT INTO @tab VALUES('A',4),('B',5),('C',6),('D',7),('E',8),('F',9),('G',1),('H',2),('I',3)
SELECT * FROM @tab ORDER BY Seq
```

Comment: So what is the problem you're having here? You haven't asked a question just stated what you want, but not explained why you haven't done whatvyou want (if you know what you need to be, please do it). Are you looking for someone to write you an ` UPDATE` statement? What have you tried so far? SO isn't a free coding service, so please help us help you and explain what the problem you're having is, show your attempts and ask a question we can answer. Thanks.

Comment: I can use update statement, but that will take a lot of time as there are many records, just want to know if there is any shortcut to that I can update them quickly

Comment: Do you actually need to change the data? Or just change the order e.g. `order by Seq desc`?

Comment: At a guess: `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I need to change the Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` is your friend here, just have to compute 2 different ones depending on the name breaking point.

```
;WITH RowNumbers AS
(
    SELECT 
        T.ID,
        RegularRowNumber = 3 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.Name),
        AfterGRowNumber = -6 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.Name),
        T.Seq,
        T.Name
    FROM 
        @tab AS T
)
UPDATE R SET
    Seq = CASE WHEN R.Name >= 'G' THEN AfterGRowNumber ELSE RegularRowNumber END
FROM
    RowNumbers AS R
```

Result:

```
ID  Name    Seq
1   A       4
2   B       5
3   C       6
4   D       7
5   E       8
6   F       9
7   G       1
8   H       2
9   I       3
```

Might want to consider using `ID` to order instead of `Name`, if appropriate.